# Silex does not use correct route

Tags: php, routes, silex

I've uploaded my working project from XAMPP to my webserver. This is the URL:

```
http://www.MyWebsite.nl/Escape/public/
```

But for some reason, Silex picks this as my main Route:

> NotFoundHttpException in RouterListener.php line 125: No route found
>   for "GET /Escape/public/"

Instead it should grab "GET /". Why does it do so and how can I fix this? Because it did work offline

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is common to define a base url in your web service configuration:

https://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.0/web_servers.html#webserver-configuration

If for some reason this is not possible you could mounting your routes to a base url like this:

```
$routes = $app['controllers_factory'];

$routes->get('/', function ($app) {
    return 'Hello world';
}

// remaining routes...

$app->mount('/Escape/public/', $routes);
```

See also: https://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.0/organizing_controllers.html